# Javadoc multiple variables on single line

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a class like the following...

```
class A{

/**
 * Blah blah
 */
 Type1 var;

/**
 * What do I do here?
 */
 Type2 var11, var12;

}
```

How can I javadoc var11, and var12 if they are both on the same line?

I am curious to see if this is possible, I know I can put them both on an individual line and javadoc from there.

Comment: Don't. Declare and document a single variable per line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was curious so I tried it out

```
/**
 * data stuff
 */
 int x , y ;
```

The resulting javadoc repeated the same doc comments for both x and y.
I imagine this behavior would be useful if two fields were essentially the same with minor differences.

```
class Circle
{
    ....
    /**
     * center coordinates
     * The x/y coordinate of the center of this circle.
     */
     int x , y ;
```

Comment: Yes, I also came to this conclusion as well. Well I guess there is no way to segregate the Javadoc, thanks for your answer & effort!

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works with the same type. So, lines like `private JButton testButton, JLabel testLabel;` won't work.

Comment: In 2022-09 Eclipse, it works, but the info/warning system does not pick it up, so the other than first fields are warned even though they go through javadoc correctly.  Suppresswarnings javadoc works to silence the warnings/info on the other than firsts.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no way to differentiate single line declaration of multiple variables :(

It may be useful to note however that the benefit of this does allow for a single javadoc to provide documentation for categorical variables which may otherwise take unnecessary lines.

```
/**
 * custom colors (MUST BE DISPOSED!)
 */
Color lightblue, someotherblue, lightred;
```

of course this can be combined with initialization as well

```
/**
*  These are the spec's behind batch-box font size / Height / Width
*/
private int iFontHeight = 9, iboxheight = 58, iboxwidth = 125;
```