# How do I document a single line where multiple variables are declared?

Tags: java, javadoc

I just ran into this little problem while documenting my code. I'm attempting to document many lines that look like the first example below, but it always gives every single variable on that line the exact same description.

Is there a way to document each variable, using only one documentation (comment?), without splitting up my variable declaration line into multiple lines?

Example 1:

```
private boolean isDamage = true, isOverTime = false, interruptable = false, canBeDispelled     = false;
```

Example 2: (How I've tried documenting.)

```
/** This is a description. */
private boolean isDamage = true, isOverTime = false, interruptable = false, canBeDispelled = false;
```

This next example is what my variable declaration area currently looks like. If I have to split up my multi-declaration lines into multiple lines then it's going to be a long mess.

```
/** The ID of the spell. */
private int id = -1;
/** The name of the spell. */
private String name = null;
private double damageMin = -1.0, damageMax = -1.0;
private double healMin = -1.0, healMax = -1.0;
private int effectTime = 1;
private double costMana = -1.0, costEnergy = -1.0, castTime = -1.0;
private boolean isDamage = true, isOverTime = false, interruptable = false, canBeDispelled = false;
/** Whether the spell is a buff or not. This only applies to buff and debuff spells. */
private boolean isBuff = false;
private int bonusStrength = 0, bonusDexterity = 0, bonusConstitution = 0, bonusIntelligence = 0, bonusWisdom = 0, bonusCharisma = 0;
private double bonusDamage = 0, bonusHealth = 0, bonusResource = 0; // bonusResource allows you to ass bonus energy or mana depending on the player's type.
```

Thanks for any replies!

Edit:
I've found, and taken a look at, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658446/javadoc-multiple-variables-on-single-line). It's pretty much what I'm asking but the answer on that post isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Put them on different lines?

Comment: I'll have to if there's no other way but I'd rather not. It would look pretty ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the variables are very straightforward so unless you're javadoc documenting, there's no need to do so. You aren't doing this, so you can just use a general wording like

`/* Defines spell behaviour */`

When another dev reads your code he will have all the information he needs from this line and the variables their names. In fact, the comment might be not needed at all since it barely adds any value.

If you do want to use javadoc documentation you'll have to split it over multiple lines.

Comment: Certainly in the example the comment is adding no useful information so should be removed. Not an uncommon situation.