# How to especify different fields in a single javadoc line?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm doing the documentation with one line for every field:

```
/** Nodo de mayor jerarquía en escena, contiene el resto de nodos incluídos.*/
    @FXML private AnchorPane anchorPane;
```

*This asigns javadoc for `anchorPane`*

But what if I have multiple fields declared in one single line:

```
@FXML private Button button1, button2, button3;
```

How can I set documentation info for every field from one single javadoc line? [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658446/javadoc-multiple-variables-on-single-line) asked this but the answer does not say whether this is possible or not.

Comment: If you want to use the same Javadoc for all three fields, the linked answer seems correct to me. If you want three different Javadocs, don't declare them on the same line.

Comment: So in a few words you suggest this is not possible?

Comment: If you want **different** Javadocs, then no. It is not possible.

Comment: Well what are we standing by Javadoc? I mean define those fields information for same documentation file(files) in a go.